# Cumulative sum of int list

Tags: recursion, functional-programming, sml, smlnj

I implemented the following functions for cumulative sum:

```
fun cumsum_reverse (xs: int list) = 
  if null xs then [0]
  else
    let val tl_cumsum = cumsum_reverse (tl xs)
    in
      hd xs + hd tl_cumsum :: tl_cumsum
    end

fun reverse (first: int list, second: int list) =
  if null first
  then
    second
  else
    reverse (tl first, hd first :: second)

fun cumsum (xs: int list) = 
  tl(reverse(cumsum_reverse(reverse(xs, [])), []))
```

Test case:

```
val test = cumsum[1,4,20] = [1,5,25]
```

Is there any way to implement this using one function only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, here is one way which I guess still uses multiple functions,
but it is just a helper to hold onto the cumulative sum, and start the recursion from 0.

However the recursive loop occurs entirely within the helper function, which is named the same to intentionally shadow the first.

```
fun cumsum (xs : int list) =
  let fun cumsum (x::xs, sum) = let val foo = x + sum in foo::cumsum(xs, foo) end
        | cumsum ([], _) = []
  in cumsum (xs, 0) end
```

Answer (score 2):

I would define this in terms of the generic `scanl` function. It resembles `foldl` but produces a list of intermediate results. It works pretty much like cumulative sum, but with the `+` operator and the default element parameterised. It's not available in the standard library, but it might as well have been.

```
fun scanl _ _ [] = []
  | scanl f y0 (x::xs) =
    let val y1 = f (x, y0)
    in y1 :: scanl f y1 xs
    end
```

and then:

```
val cumsum = scanl op+ 0
```

> Is there any way to implement this using one function only?

It depends on what you mean by "one function only".

Only one function at all? `cumsum` only takes one list as input, and you need an extra argument for keeping track of the accumulated sum. Since the function that accumulates the result cannot be `cumsum` directly, you need two functions. So do you mean "one named function besides `cumsum`"? Then `scanl` or matt's inner helper function would solve this.

If you can only define `cumsum` using standard-library functions:

```
val cumsum = tl o rev o foldl (fn (x, y::ys) => x + y :: y :: ys) [0]
```

Then `cumsum` becomes the only function that you declare.

And if you can only define `cumsum` using a single standard-library function, I'd go with `foldl`:

```
val cumsum = (fn (_::xs) => xs)  (* tl *)
           o foldl op:: []       (* rev *)
           o foldl (fn (x, y::ys) => x + y :: y :: ys) [0]
```

Then `cumsum` becomes the only function that you declare, and you've only used one named standard-library function to do it. (If it were not a standard-library function, you'd have to declare it, and then you'd have declared two functions.)

But this is getting a little silly. :-)